# How to change working of top command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, linux-kernel, docker-container

I am running a docker container which has /proc /sys by default when I mount my host volumes to docker using

> docker run -it -v /proc/:/nodeserver/proc/:ro -v /sys/fs/cgroup/:/nodeserver/sys/fs/cgroup:ro giri/ubuntu:latest

By using the above command I have mounted my host's /proc and /sys to /nodeserver/proc and /nodeserver/sys respectively. Now if I use top or ps command, what it gives is the detail about the running process in the container by using the /proc and /sys directory. Is it possible to make the top command work from /nodeserver/proc instead of /proc by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a `mount --bind  /nodeserver/proc /proc` in your container. See [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html)

Read also [about cgroups](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html) (I am not very familiar with them)

Comment: Thanks bro u made my day

Comment: But is there any way to distinguish container process and host process from the top or pa command outputs