# how to redirect ps command in linux to look into other folder than /proc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, ps

I am using docker containers and I have mounted host /proc to container /host/proc. Now I want ps command inside docker container to look for processes into /host/proc instead of /proc.
or how can I right similar utility to ps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `/proc` path is hardcoded in the source tree of the `/bin/ps` binary file.
**Thus, you need to recompile `/bin/ps`**

Follow these steps to recompile `/bin/ps` inside a container that mounts the host `/proc` and use this new `ps` to display the process list of the docker host from the container:

**In this example, I do not use `/host/proc` but `/prod`, to avoid modifying the path length to the mount point of the procfs filesystem (increasing the path length could trigger runtime errors in some situations).** I also use a container based on OpenSUSE Leap 42.1, since you have not described the base image you are using.

1- on the docker host, first download the /bin/ps sources:

```
fenyo@myhost# mkdir /root/git
fenyo@myhost# cd /root/git
fenyo@myhost# git clone https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps.git
fenyo@myhost# cd procps
```

2- replace any occurence of `"/proc` by `"/prod` in **/*.c

3- run your docker container, mounting procfs on `/prod` in the container

```
fenyo@myhost# docker run -v /proc:/prod -v /root/git/procps:/root/git/procps -t -i --rm opensuse:42.1 bash
```

4- inside the docker container, recompile `/bin/ps`

```
bash-4.2# cd /root/git/procps
bash-4.2# zypper install -y gettext gettext-tools autoconf libtool pkg-config gcc make
bash-4.2# ./autogen.sh
bash-4.2# ./configure --without-ncurses
bash-4.2# make
```

Now, you can use `/root/git/procps/ps/pscommand` as a replacement for `/bin/ps`, in order to use `/prod` instead of `/proc`. With `pscommand`, you will get a process list from the host, not from the container:

```
bash-4.2# ps -auxgww
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  20064  3076 ?        Ss   23:20   0:00 bash
root      5199  0.0  0.0  33340  2996 ?        R+   23:24   0:00 ps -auxgww

bash-4.2# /root/git/procps/ps/pscommand -auxgww
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  33620  3956 ?        Ss   Jul03   1:13 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 21
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:01 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        R    Jul03   4:44 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jul03   0:01 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03  15:27 [rcu_preempt]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:00 [rcu_sched]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03  10:02 [rcuop/0]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:00 [rcuos/0]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:00 [rcuob/0]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:06 [migration/0]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:07 [watchdog/0]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:06 [watchdog/1]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:04 [migration/1]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   1:07 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jul03   0:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   2:42 [rcuop/1]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:00 [rcuos/1]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:00 [rcuob/1]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:05 [watchdog/2]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:06 [migration/2]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:48 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jul03   0:00 [kworker/2:0H]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   7:32 [rcuop/2]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:00 [rcuos/2]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:00 [rcuob/2]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:05 [watchdog/3]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:05 [migration/3]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul03   0:37 [ksoftirqd/3]
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and confirm if this works for me. Can I do similar thing for kill command also?

Comment: No, it will not work with `kill` because `kill` does not use `/proc`. It makes use of a system call, and when running in a Docker container, this system call does not see the processes that run on the host. There is no way to send a signal to kill a host process from inside a container.

Comment: Actually I have tried it with "--pid host" it mount host pid namespace to container. and kill command worked. But I am deploying container on AWS ecs and unfortunately ecs agent does not provide the parameter  --pid. Thank for your help

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we have same issue with dockerizing monitoring tool which has to use ps. No luck with recompiling to /prod - it tried to read /prod/self/stats but somehow it non-existing symlink. So... it drops "Error, do this: mount -t proc proc /proc"  Strange because this code exists in procps 10 years or so. Probably docker behavior for symlinks is different for you and me.
I've used -v /proc:/prod like you.  

Anyway a guy suggests just remonunt /proc in container  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44208453/3479125 works, but requires SYS_ADMIN cap (not nice)